# 4 states Markov Chain and invariant measure

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Does there exist a Markov Chain with $4$ states and a unique invariant measure $\pi$ such that $\pi_{1}= \pi_{3} = 0$ and $\pi_{2}, \pi_{4} > 0$?

I couldn't think of an example  off the top of my head with this property. If it actually doesn't exist, how to prove such a Markov chain cannot exist?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just make $1$ and $3$ transient while 2 and 4 are both recurrent, for example $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$. Note that if you assume the invariant measure is *unique* and has these properties then these transience/recurrence behaviors are also necessary.

Comment: But why is the invariant measure unique in this case? Is it because $\pi_{2}$ has to equal $\pi_{4}$ in order to satisfy the equations?

Comment: @kkkkstein Right.

Comment: @kkkkstein More generally, there is only one communicating class here, namely $\{ 2,4 \}$, so there is only one invariant distribution.